# System.Transactions.TransactionException

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I've got the following code :

```
[TestMethod]
        public void CalculateThatWeHaveAllRetrunFromProxyImmo()
        {
            var test = new BaseDataAccess();
            var sessionDateParam = new SqlParameter("@SessionDate", new DateTime(1900, 01, 31));
            var dateDebutParam = new SqlParameter("@DateDebutHistoricRendement", new DateTime(1999, 01, 31));
            var datefinParam = new SqlParameter("@DateFinHistoricRendement", new DateTime(2015, 01, 31));
            var idProxyParam = new SqlParameter("@IdRealEstateProxy", 15);
            var blocElementParam = new SqlParameter("@BlocNbrElement", 1501);

            for (int index = 0; index < 17; index++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Passage : " + index);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                SqlConnection conn = null;
                using (conn = test.CreateAndOpenConnection())
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = null;
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand("[Core].[cp_CalculAllReturnProxyImmo]", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000000;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(sessionDateParam);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(dateDebutParam);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(datefinParam);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(idProxyParam);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(blocElementParam);

                        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            adapter.Fill(ds);
                        }

                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
```

And

```
/// <summary>
        ///     Creates our connection to the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The SqlConnection object.</returns>
        public SqlConnection CreateAndOpenConnection()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = null;

            try
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.DbConnection);
                connection.Open(); // the error appears here after 14 iterations

            }
            catch (SqlException sqlException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }

            return connection;
        }
```

Here is the connection

```
connectionString="Data Source=xxx\yyy;Initial Catalog=BD;Integrated Security=True;Max Pool Size=5000"
```

And every time I arrive at the index 14 in my loop, I get a `System.Transactions.TransactionException`.
But I don't have any transaction open in my code.  I don't understand.

Here is the complete Stack :

```
à 

System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   à System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction transaction)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, ref DbConnectionInternal connection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, ref DbConnectionInternal connection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, ref DbConnectionInternal connection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   à System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   à System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   à System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
   à MarketRisk.dVar.IntegrationTests.Service.Managers.RealEstateProxyCreationManagerFixture.CalculateThatWeHaveAllRetrunFromProxyImmo() dans RealEstateProxyCreationManagerFixture.cs: line 67
```

The debug trace :

Debug Trace:

```
Passage : 0
Passage : 1
Passage : 2
Passage : 3
Passage : 4
Passage : 5
Passage : 6
Passage : 7
Passage : 8
Passage : 9
Passage : 10
Passage : 11
Passage : 12
Test method 
MarketRisk.dVar.IntegrationTests.Service.Managers.RealEstateProxyCreationManagerFixture.CalculateThatWeHaveAllRetrunFromProxyImmo Threw exception :
System.Transactions.TransactionException : The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction. ---> System.TimeoutException : Delay transaction time
```

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Missing the stored procedure code, but try to open explicitly the connection without leaving this task to the SqlDataAdapter

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving this task to the SqlDataAdapter" ?

Comment: Wrong me. Not noticed that the connection is opened after the creation. However, if you set a closed connection to an adapter (explicitly or via command) the adapter opens and close it in the Fill. Still the reason of the failure is not clear. Perhaps something in the stored procedure called

Comment: Add `Assert.IsTrue(Transaction.Current == null);`. This assert will fire. Maybe the previous test abandoned a transaction. Cross test interaction.

Comment: Maybe it's my stored procedure. However, it works for the 11 first items and it always stop at the 12 element, and when i take the 12 element alone, no problem. Also, i'm supprised that i have a Transaction Exception. I don't open any transactions in my code. Everything working whit using so everything is dispose at the end, supposedly.

Comment: Did you add the assert as I asked? It sounds like you didn't. Why?

Comment: I just did, I did not have time earlier. that assert throw me a exception, the current transaction is not null. But i don't really understand why i have a transaction since i did not put my code inside a transaction Scope. I sone as i start the code, right before my loop, there is alerady a transaction created. Should i kill that Transaction (transaction.current = null) ? thanks

Comment: Your two empty catch statements in your connection open don't smell good to me - you need to get rid of those.  Also, what is your sproc doing?

Comment: Having a separate code block (CreateAndOpenConnection) that opens DB connections is also a smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested you added `Assert.IsTrue(Transaction.Current == null);` to the test. The assert fired. This proves that there is a `System.Transactions.Transaction` set that you did not know about. That explains the symptoms. You are inadvertently using distributed transactions (you better disable the MSDTC service if you don't use them so that they fail immediately instead of only sometimes!).

Impossible to tell where that transaction is instated. Grep the entire source code for "Transaction". Add more asserts.

Probably, a different test has set that transaction and leaked it. Cross-test interaction is nasty to debug. Narrow it down by gradually reducing the set of tests that you run until the problem disappears.

> Should i kill that Transaction

That is inappropriate. find the root cause instead of treating the symptom. There should be no tran that you don't know about.

Comment: You were right. A transaction opened in a base class. by removing that base class, the problem disappeared.I do not know how I missed this information, but i missed it. Thank for this assert. For me the problem is resolved. Thanks